# Apache tomcat was not starting

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I had installed Apache Tomcat for my academic purpose but I don't know the reson why but my server was not starting. I only thing I changed during the installation of tomcat is change the port from 8080 to 3000.

This was the screenshot after clicking start.
[Tomcat window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3xI.png)
I was currently using JAVA jdk-11.0.15.1. I had added CLASSPATH, JAVA_HOME in enivroment variables.

[Enivronmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dGuh.png)

[Java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWigb.png)

[JVM PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFlgr.png)

Comment: What do the logs say?   When you attempt to start it?

Comment: Please, put the images and code on your question, not in links

Comment: did you connect your spring project to an database? how do you want to do on your project?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].